# Scaling sketches to different resolutions

Tags: java, processing

Now this may seem like a silly question, but hear me out please.

Until this point, whenever I wanted to create a sketch that would run on multiple resolutions, i'd place certain objects, like an `ellipse()` on say `width/2, height/2, width/16, width/16` to make a circle (yes I know there's a circle function but that's not the point).

However when creating more precise objects that hold some detail, it'd get annoying real fast to have to do `width/2.489` or whatever when the same effect could be achieved with `width/2 - someNumber`

Say I'm drawing a `Duck` object I want to display at `x` and `y` I'd like to be able to have the `Duck`'s `draw()` method list like `circle(x,y, 100); circle(x + someNum, y, 25);`

I could opt for having a standard size, like `int STD = width / 100` and then adding these little details by doing something like `circle(x + STD * 3, y, 25);` but that too feels unelegant.

I know Processing has a `scale()` option but unfortunately there's no way to scale just the `heights` and `widths` of objects being drawn. It scales the position stuff is draw at too.

So, if I first draw a sketch on `size(1920/2 * 1080/2)` and have a circle on say `width / 2, height / 2` and then run the sketch on `size(1920,1080)` and `scale(2)` it will draw the circle at `width / 2 * 2` and put the circle almost off-screen

So... what is the most elegant way to draw detailed objects for varying resolutions? ( but same aspect ratio)

Answer (score 0):

I did something like that a couple years back. Mine was waaay too complicated to just share the code, but I'll gladly share the principle.

To achieve this, I based everything I wanted to show in the sketch on a `Drawable` base class, with a `Render` method which would, well, draw them. As everything would inherit this one-to-rule-them-all method, I could then implement a way to resize and replace everything at draw time.

So I decided on a "official" resolution, which was the scale at which everything was for real, and at draw time my base class would correct the positions and scale of every objects, and I didn't have to do a damn thing once that part had been coded once.

Here's a very simplified implementation of this logic:

We start with a global variable to scale everything the same way:

```
final float scaleNum = 3.0;
```

I used a fancy ENUM to decide on how the (yet to write) Drawable class would choose how it'll render the Drawable. For this to work, you must declare the enum in a `fileName.java` file, because Processing doesn't like enums so you have to fall back on java for this one. If you don't want to do this, you can use anything else, like a very simple string, if you prefer. Here's my enum:

```
//In Enums.java
enum Shape
{
  RECTANGLE,
  TRIANGLE,
  ELLIPSE
};
```

Then we write a base class for everything drawable. This one is designed to deal with only a handful op possibilities, but you seem to be able to sort this kind of detail out easily.

```
class Drawable {
  PVector position;
  boolean isVisible;
  float w, h;
  color fill = color(255,255,255);
  color stroke = color(255,255,255);
  float strokeWeight = 1;
  int shape;

  public Drawable (int shape) {
    this.shape = shape;
    position = new PVector(0,0);
    isVisible = true;
  }

  public void Render(){
    if (isVisible) {
      stroke(this.stroke);
      strokeWeight(this.strokeWeight);
      fill(this.fill);
      switch (shape) {
        case RECTANGLE:
          rect(position.x * scaleNum , position.y * scaleNum , w * scaleNum , h * scaleNum );
          break;
        case TRIANGLE:
          //code to draw a triangle at scale
          break;
        case ELLIPSE:
          //code to draw an ellipsis at scale
          break;
      }        
    }
  }
}
```

Now, here's an example of a class inheriting the `Drawable` class:

```
class Paddle extends Drawable{
  PVector speed; // some class-specific variable

  Paddle (float positionX, float positionY) {
    super(RECTANGLE);  // this calls the parent class Constructor

    speed = new PVector(5, 5); //initializing stuff
    position = new PVector (positionX, positionY);
  }

  public void Move() { //class-specific method. Notice how it doesn't need to be scaled.
    position.x += speed.x;
    position.y += speed.y;
  }
}
```

Now, as a bonus functionality, since everything drawable inherits the same `Drawable` class, you can create a list of everything drawable and add whatever you want to draw to it and let it sort himself out instead of micro-managing everything in your program. I mean, if you have a ton of things to draw, this is awesome:

```
ArrayList <Drawable> myDrawables;

void setup () {
  myDrawables = new Arraylist <Drawables>;
  myDrawable.add(new Paddle(0, 0));
  Hero myHeroicCharacter = new Hero();
  myDrawables.add(myHeroicCharacter);
  myDrawable.add(new anotherClass(someVariables));
  //etc.  
}

void draw () {
  for (Drawable drawable : myDrawables) {
    drawable.Render();
  }
}
```

I don't think that this is objectively the best approach, but it certainly is a very simple and manageable one. Have fun!

Comment: Interesting approach I might look into more if I'd start large-scale projects. Not exactly what I'm looking for however.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to take arbitrary coordinates (which I will refer to as being in "world space") and map them to "screen space" (the pixels on your display). The best way of doing this is indeed with `scale()`; However, in your code you used `scale(2)` (mapping from world space to *bigger world space*), and then you drew at screen space coordinates with `width / 2, height / 2` (which normally would have been in the middle of your screen space, but since you scaled by 2 earlier, your `width / 2` and `height / 2` are being multiplied by 2).

Instead, you should use `scale()` to map from world space to screen space, and draw your objects using world space coordinates. Example:

```
// World space of 400 x 400, chosen arbitrarily
final float worldWidth = 400.0
  , worldHeight = 400.0;

void draw() {
  // Map the world space (of 400 x 400) to screen space
  /* Another way of thinking about this:
       A value on the X scale of 0 to 400 is divided by 400 into the scale of 0.0 to 1.0,
       and then is multiplied by the actual width of the screen;
       Whatever fraction of the world space's width it was at,
       it's now at that same fraction of the screen space's width.
  */
  scale(width/worldWidth, height/worldHeight);

  // Convert mouse coordinates from screen space to world space
  /* Explanation:
   We need to convert mouse coordinates from screen space to world space
   if we want to use their values in world space (scale only affects drawing).
   mouseX and mouseY are only changed when the mouse is moved;
   If we converted on frames where they haven't been updated,
   the conversions would accumulate.
   pmouseX and pmouseY are set to mouseX and mouseY between draw() calls.
   */
  if (pmouseX != mouseX || pmouseY != mouseY) {
    mouseX = round(mouseX * worldWidth / width);
    mouseY = round(mouseY * worldHeight / height);
  }

  // Example drawing code:
  background(64);
  // Same as ellipse(width/2, height/2, width/16, height/16) when not scaling
  ellipse(200, 200, 25, 25);
  // Same as ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, width/16, height/16) when not scaling
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 25, 25);
}
```

---

If you want to correct for screen ratio, so that when you draw something of equal width and height it comes out as a square no matter what ratio your screen has, you can do:

```
// World space of 1600 x 900 (16:9), chosen arbitrarily
final float worldWidth = 1600.0
  , worldHeight = 900.0;

void draw() {
  // Uniformly scale the world space so that it just fits the screen
  float toScreenScale = min(width/worldWidth, height/worldHeight);
  // Or: Uniformly scale the world space so that the screen just fits inside it
  // float toScreenScale = max(width/worldWidth, height/worldHeight);
  // Draw in the middle of the borders (when using min for toScreenScale)
  float xBorder = (width - worldWidth * toScreenScale) / 2.0;
  float yBorder = (height - worldHeight * toScreenScale) / 2.0;
  translate(xBorder, yBorder);
  // Scale world space uniformly
  scale(toScreenScale);

  // Convert mouse coordinates from screen space to world space
  if (pmouseX != mouseX || pmouseY != mouseY) {
    mouseX = round( (mouseX - xBorder) / toScreenScale );
    mouseY = round( (mouseY - yBorder) / toScreenScale );
  }

  // Example drawing code:
  background(64);
  stroke(0);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(800, 450, 56.25, 56.25);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 56.25, 56.25);

  // Draw border to avoid spill-out (when using min for toScreenScale)
  noStroke();
  fill(0);
  resetMatrix();
  // Top
  rect(0, 0, width, yBorder);
  // Bottom
  rect(0, height, width, -yBorder);
  // Left
  rect(0, 0, xBorder, height);
  // Right
  rect(width, 0, -xBorder, height);
}
```

This will give you borders if your world space's and screen space's ratios aren't the same. If you don't fill in those borders manually (using `rect()`, **after** you've drawn everything else), things might spill out into the borders. If you use `max` for `toScreenScale`, it'll cut things off instead of border them.

---

#### Notes:

- When we scale `mouseX` or `mouseY` to a world space that is bigger than the screen space, the rounding will make mouse coordinates inaccurate; Instead, you're better off making a new pair of `float` coordinates (or a `PVector`), but you'll need to replace all occurrences of `mouseX` and `mouseY` in your code with that new variable.

---

*There are no silly questions*